# allow access to local nodeJS server from different computer on different network

Tags: node.js, networking

I am running nodeJS server on the local machine, that is accessible from other computers inside a local network (within LAN ). But I want this local server can be accessible from anywhere on the Internet, need your help!

here is the code snippet I am using :

```
server.listen(CONFIG.serverPort,"0.0.0.0");
```

Comment: Then it is already. Rest is networking setup, which isn't SO material and you explain nothing about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no , it can only be accessible via only on local network(LAN), otherwise you have to put it on server and then run it.

Comment: Can you explain why? that will help me a lot.

Comment: i never run local app with different computer on different network,may be it is possible, i have found something ,check this https://www.sitepoint.com/accessing-localhost-from-anywhere/, i am not sure about that ,may be it works.